# how can i access database from broadcast receiver in android?

Tags: android

i am developing a alarm application using `BroadcastReceiver`. Here i need to check whether the alarm is on or off from the database. So i need to check the status of the alarm when the broadcast event came. I have to put the database access code in `BroadcastReceiver` class `onReceive()` method. Here suggest me if there is any way to access the data from the `BroadcastReceiver`

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no real problem accessing the DB from the BroadcashReceiver.
You will need the context, which you have as part of the BroadcastReceiver onReceive method signature and that's it.
If you're facing a specific problem, please tell us what it is

Comment: Here i can not give the context like                            alarmDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null); here  what can i use instead of this to represent the context

Comment: onReceive receives the context as a parameter. Just call: context.openOrCreateDatabase ...

Comment: Thanks i confused about the context.If u don't mine can u clarify what is context.

Comment: You actually shouldn't use openOrCreateDatabase directly... You should use SQliteOpenHelper. Look at this link to understand how to use it. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: i can`t delete entries in sqlite database.