# Perform code when the Android application is closed

Tags: android, database, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an application that detects incoming text messages.

When a message is received, the application must perform a certain action, depending on the sender and the content.

The problem is that the application must work at all times. 
Detecting messages works through a BroadcastReceiver class. Via a Toast message I can see that the application (open or closed) receives the message.

The problem then is that I must perform certain actions, which are stored in a local database (DB40). But I can't access the database when the application is closed.

So, how can I perform database access and run other code (like making the phone vibrate, or play a ringtone) when the application is closed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the DataBase... because you are getting the **context** from the receiver, from the context create the instance of the Database and go further according to your requirement..

Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319428/how-can-i-access-database-from-broadcast-receiver-in-android)...

Comment: I already tried that, but I'll try combining it with services for further code too. thanks for your response =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a service to perform all the task even app is closed.

Just go through with few sample and study:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about Services?

You can use service as back-end to perform action on incoming messages or can use database.

Database need only 'Context' object for read/write and service provide 'Context' object by 'getApplicationContext()' method.

If you have any ambiguity about answer, just give me your little code, i will give you back with solution.