# app crashes when alarm triggers if app is closed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

Get Exception :

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   TABLE_USER_RITUALS (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from
>   TABLE_USER_RITUALS where USER_NAME = 'vxfbb' and RITUAL_NAME =
>   'Morning Routine'

But the database is exists as the code works fine if the app is opened in background, it got crashed when app is removed from the background

Broadcast Receiver Class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    String h_id, habit, habit_desc, habit_time;
    //public static Ringtone ringtone;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent arg1) 
    {
        String selectedRitual = arg1.getExtras().getString(AppsConstant.SELECTED_RITUAL);
        String userName = arg1.getExtras().getString(AppsConstant.user_name);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(mContext, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); 

        //get data from database        
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        UserRitualModel userReminderSetting  = getData.getRitualsDetails(userName, selectedRitual);
        int isfullScreen = userReminderSetting.getNotificationStyle();
        int ringInSilent = userReminderSetting.getRingInSilent();

        if(ringInSilent ==TableAttributes.ON)
        {
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES); 
        }


        Intent i;
        if(isfullScreen==TableAttributes.ON)
        {
              i = new Intent(mContext, ReminderFullScreen.class);
        }
        else
        {
            i = new Intent(mContext, Reminder.class);  
        }
       // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra(AppsConstant.SELECTED_RITUAL, selectedRitual);
        i.putExtra(AppsConstant.user_name, userName);

        mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are not deleting the database on destroy of your activity

Comment: The exception message is pretty explicit, a  table is missing

Comment: if you have made any changes in the database then remove application otherwise clear catch or data,then it may be work fine if all is ok

Comment: Just uninstall your app and re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer :

You will need the context,for calling the database which you have as part of the BroadcastReceiver onReceive method signature and that's it.

for refrence :
[how can i access database from broadcast receiver in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319428/how-can-i-access-database-from-broadcast-receiver-in-android)